# Force DCOM application to start in the foreground

Tags: windows-10-iot-core, dcom

I have an application I'm working on. It has a DCOM component. When accessing it from another server the application starts and responds fine.

However, it starts in the background. This is not the behavor I want. I want it to start normally.

I'm porting the application from XP to Windows 10. In XP, it does not have this behavour.

How can I force the application to start in the foreground?

Comment: Have you configured your DCOM server to run as the [Interactive User](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686587(v=vs.85).aspx)? In Windows XP, it was possible for services to interact with the user. That has [since been changed](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683502(v=vs.85).aspx) and services that still need to interact with the user need to be flagged as such.

Comment: @SeanCline's comment pointed me in the right direction. I set COM Components identity to 'interactive user'. Then set pSecDesc value of CoInitializeSecurity call to the GUID of COM component (was NULL).

Comment: @dagur Sounds interesting, could you post a self-answer with that if it resolved your problem?